# How can I combine two fields into one when importing from a file into numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data file which I am reading into a numpy array which looks like the following.

```
#RIC,Date[G],Time[G],GMT Offset,Type,Open,High,Low,Last,Volume
ADH0,20100103,22:18:00.000,-6,Intraday 1Min,0.8915,0.8915,0.8915,0.8915,0
ADH0,20100103,22:22:00.000,-6,Intraday 1Min,0.89,0.89,0.89,0.89,0
```

I am reading it using the `np.genfromtxt()` function as follows:

```
a = np.genfromtxt(f, names=True, delimiter=',', dtype="|S8,i4,|S12,f8", usecols=(0, 1, 2, 8), autostrip=True)
```

All is fine, but I would like to combine the date and time fields into one datetime column in my array instead of separate columns. I can do the individual field conversion using a converter function, but I can't see a way of combining the two separate date and time fields into one datetime. Can this be done?

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, it might be easier if you just slice'n'dice the csv file before loading, for example with a very stupid script like this:

```
gawk -F, '{print $1","$2"_"$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10}' input.csv
```

This will combine field 2 and 3 with an underscore, and you can use a timestamp stringparser on it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I don't think there is a way to do this from within `np.genfromtxt`. Your best bet is probably to read in the data as you are currently doing, and then create a new array that combines the two columns as a later step.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned about speed, this is a fairly direct way, albeit an eyeful:

```
raw_csv = csv.reader(open('file'))
joined_columns = np.array([[[i[0]]+[str(i[1])+'sep_string'+str(i[2])]+i[3:]]\
                 for i in raw_csv])
```